# How to disable underline in a button

Tags: html, css, button, href

I have an A (html tag) with href. I converted it to a button with css. Now, when I move the mouse cursor above it, the text gets underlined. I don't want that happen. The question is... Can I disable the underline?

HTML

```
<td><a href="url" target="_blank" class="btnBuy">Buy it</a></td>
```

Comment: Perhaps `a:hover { text-decoration: none }`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can.

```
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```